# watchOS 2 WatchConnectivity Time lag between Apple Watch and iPhone while sending data from one to another?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I am using WatchConnectivity (`WCSession`) to pass info from Apple Watch to iPhone, but I see there is a (10-15 secs) of lag between Apple Watch and iPhone. For connectivity I am using `session.sendMessage()` and `session.didReceiveMessage()`. There is a lot of lag between Apple Watch and iPhone. I have  also tried `updateApplicationContext()`, but I see no difference in the lag. Is there any other way to handle the lag between them?

Thanks

Comment: Can we use "Multipeer Connectivity" framework for communication between watch and iphone app?? is there any tutorial for that?

Comment: How large are the messages you are sending? Do you seen the same slowness even with a tiny dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using iOS 9 Beta 5 and I have not had any noticeable lag on my real devices. Transfer time is normally with a second or two. However, this will greatly depend on the size of the message object you are trying to send. When I first was sending data my object was too large and it was timing out around 30 seconds. After trimming it down to a more manageable size, it has been quite performant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's hard to find info about optimizing watchOS. Curious, what size dictionary would you say is too large to be performant?

Comment: I believe my slow payload had been a few megabytes, and my optimized payload was a few kilobytes. For larger payloads, the file transfer specific APIs are likely more appropriate.